# Send AT-command through bluetooth with python

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, at-command, rfcomm

I try to send AT commands from my computer (ubuntu 13.04) to my phone (Android 5.1) via bluetooth. I want to read the SMS.

I retrieve the MAC address of my phone with :

```
hcitool scan
```

I browse all available services on the device with :

```
sdptool browse XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

I get the good RFCOMM channel for SMS/MMS service and now I'm trying to send the AT command.

I tried with pySerial with a bound and connected rfcomm to my phone but no response :

```
import serial

phone = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0', 115200, timeout=2)
phone.write(b'AT\r')
data = phone.readall()
print data
```

I tried the same code on a USB serial port and I have a response :

```
import serial

phone = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=2)
phone.write(b'AT\r')
data = phone.readall()
print data

# *EMRDY: 1

# AT
# OK
```

I tried with pyBluez but same problem, no response of my AT command :

```
import bluetooth

client_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
client_sock.connect(('XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX', 4))
client_sock.send(b'AT\r')
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data
```

And I finally tried with native python sockets, but no response :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect(('XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX',4))
s.send(b'AT\r')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Received', repr(data))
```

Note: The phone displays a prompt window to accept that my computer accesses my sms. Of course I accepted.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and what I can try?

Comment: Just a debugging idea: maybe sending the AT command right after connection fails, try to add a delay between and see if that makes any difference?.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starter it is better to check first that you have a two-way communication between your Host computer and your Phone on bluetooth, like you said, it did work with USB, then there should be no reason it does not with bluetooth unless you didn't yet established a good communication, so I think it is better to try first that you have good communication by just sending and replying with the same string (kinda hand-shaking protocol) and make sure that you know what your python code is actually sending, may be unseen extra characters using bluetooth that you don't pay attention to, which makes your AT command unrecognizable by your phone.

Comment: Yes, but how can I test my communication between the computer and the phone ? I pinged the device with l2ping, is it enough ? I know how to send a string from the computer to the phone, but I don't understand how the phone can respond if no code is running on the phone.